# Align a button at the bottom of its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Having these elements, I want to button to be situated at the bottom of the red div, inside of it.

```css
 .grand-parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .parent {
        margin: 12.5px;
        flex-grow: 0;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 25px);
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .table {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: grey;
    }


    .button {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 2px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 10px 0;
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
 <div class="parent">
  <table class="table">
  </table>
  <button class="button">CLICK</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make this `button` to be situated at the bottom of its container (`parent` in this case), it is all the time right below `table`.

I've tried with `justify-content`, `justify-items`, `align-self` and many others but didn't reach to the correct combination.

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question.

Comment: @Turnip, I created it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.parent` element `display: flex;` then use `justify-content: space-between` to push the button to the bottom of the element.

```css
.grand-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.parent {
  margin: 12.5px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 25px);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start; /* Prevent button stretching full width */
}

.table {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
}

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="button">CLICK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: 
Remove these code in the .grand-parent css
`display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.grand-parent {
        
        height: 300px;
        background-color: green;

    }

    .parent {
        margin: 12.5px;
        flex-grow: 0;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 25px);
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .table {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: grey;
    }


    .button {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 2px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px 0;
        
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
 <div class="parent">
  <table class="table">
  
  </table>
 </div>
 <div>
 <button class="button">CLICK</button>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong. I want it to be inside the green div ( the smaller div) at the end of it but inside of it